# Check whether an element is a parent of a given element

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

how can i check, if clicked element is not child of some specific DIV element?

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if(e NOT child of $('#someDiv')) alert(1);
});
```

Comment: Do you mean child or descendant?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if ($(e.target).parent('#someDiv').length == 0) {
    ...
}
```

Or, did you mean ("not an ancestor of e"):

```
if ($(e.target).closest('#someDiv').length == 0) {
```

Comment: `.closest()` starts with the element itself and stops if it finds something. if by any chance the selector matches the child (like say using a class), it will return itself. `.parents()` would be safer.

Comment: @Joseph Nicely spotted. Then use `.parent().closest('#someDiv')`.

Comment: @RobW missed that one. i thought the OP meant to use something `.on` or `.delegate`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `parent` method with a selector to return the parent element if it matches that selector. You can then check the `length` property to see if the parent element was returned:

```
$("body").click(function(e) {
    if(!$(this).parent("#someDiv").length) {
        alert("Not a child");
    }
});
```

If you want to check whether the clicked element is not an *ancestor*, you can use `parents` instead of `parent`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('yourElement').on('click',function(){
      if(!$(this).parents('theDiv').length){
          //not a child
      }
});
```